# Union and group two collections without any common field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

How to get all requests of a user grouped and order by create date? Please give mongodb compass aggregation in order to export c# code or codes that be suitable for c#.
My database is MongoDB. I use $group and $push it's work but only for a collection. I cant union the other collection.
The data is here:

```
    PaymentRequestCollection:
    [
      { _id: 1, createDate: "2022-01-10T19:43:57.625Z", UserId: 5, amount: 24 },
      { _id: 2, createDate: "2022-01-12T16:43:57.625Z", UserId: 14, amount: 34},
      { _id: 3, createDate: "2022-01-12T12:43:57.625Z", UserId: 8, amount: 20 },
      { _id: 4, createDate: "2022-01-10T15:43:57.625Z", UserId: 14, amount: 54 },
    ]
    
    JobRequestCollection:
    [
      { _id: 24, createDate: "2022-01-12T11:43:57.625Z", UserId: 14, jobTitle: "team leader", subscriptionId: 52 },
      { _id: 25, createDate: "2022-01-10T17:43:57.625Z", UserId: 14, jobTitle: "front-end developer", subscriptionId: 52 },
      { _id: 26, createDate: "2022-01-18T13:43:57.625Z", UserId: 8, jobTitle: ".net back-end developer", subscriptionId: 10 },
    ]
    
    SubscriptionCollection:
    [
      { _id:10, title: "some title 1" },
      { _id:52, title: "some title 2" }
    ]
```

```
Expected result for user with id 14:
```

```
    [
       {
       "key": "2022-01-10",
           "group": [
               {
                   "requestType": "PaymentRequest",
                   "amount": "54"
               },
               {
                   "requestType": "JobRequest",
                   "jobTitle": "front-end developer",
                   "subscription": {
                       "title": "some title 2"
                   }
               },
           ]
       },
       {
       "key": "2022-01-12",
           "group": [
               {
                   "requestType": "PaymentRequest",
                   "amount": "34"
               },
               {
                   "requestType": "JobRequest",
                   "jobTitle": "team leader",
                   "subscription": {
                       "title": "some title 2"
                   }
               },
           ]
       }
    ]
```

```
Thanks
```

Comment: this may be close https://mongoplayground.net/p/-nx4eZVtO4l
for user 14

Comment: check the suggested query, might be close to what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71078962/is-there-a-mongodb-runcommand-that-returns-multiple-collections/71082353#71082353