# Is there a mongoDB runCommand that returns multiple collections?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to write a mongoDB runCommand that returns multiple collections with one command.

I have successfully used the [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/) command within runCommand but I'm unsure how to return multiple find searches. It's important that they are not merged.

Something similar to:

```
db.runCommand(
   [{
      "find": "venues"
   },
   {
      "find": "guests"
   }]
)
```

Ideally the result would follow something similar to this structure:

```
{
  "venues": {all venue data from mongo},
  "guests": {all guest data from mongo}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, this question has nothing common with `runCommand`.`RunCommand` just runs a *single* command. What you really need is to use [unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/) aggregate stage and possibly some post data processing.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $unionWith: {
      coll: "inventory",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $addFields: {
            "fromInventory": 1  // add a flag that shows that this data is not from original collection
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$fromInventory",
      "content": {
        "$addToSet": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "content": 1, // also it's possible to exclude a flag from output via: `"content.fromInventory": 0,` instead `"content" : 1`
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

See [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RfBWu9xZRF9). You may need to improve this result further for example with `$replaceRoot`